# How to display a linked list in C

Tags: c, linked-list

I am a beginner in **linked list** in **c**. First to understand the concept I am trying to make a simple linked list.
  Here is the code  :

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>


typedef struct Element ELEMENT;
struct Element
{
    float price;
    int nb_products;
    ELEMENT *next=NULL;
};

ELEMENT* add_list ( ELEMENT * p_head)
{

    ELEMENT* my_new=NULL;

    if (!( my_new = (ELEMENT*) malloc (sizeof(ELEMENT))))
    {
        printf ("Pb d'allocation dans %s\n",__func__);
        exit (EXIT_FAILURE);
    }
    my_new->next = p_head;
    return my_new;
}

void liste_display(ELEMENT *p_head)
{
    while(p_head != NULL)
    {
        printf("%d",p_head->nb_products);
        p_head = p_head->next;
    }
}
int main()
{
    ELEMENT *head = NULL;
    ELEMENT *elem;

    elem = add_list(head);

    elem->nb_products = 34;
    elem->price       = 10.95;

    liste_display ( head );

    return 0;
}
```

I can manage to create a new element in my list of ELEMENT but I don't know how to display it (in the code there is only one element to display).

As you can see I have an error EXC_BAD_ACCESS so I guess I did not understand how to manipulate a linked list.

Later in my project I will need (if it is possible) to make linked list of linked list (like a sort of 2d array but in list) and I did not find out how to make this. For exemple if an element of my list of ELEMENT  has to have a list of another kind of struct, shall I declare a *head pointer in the ELEMENT struct ?

Thanks by advance.

Comment: Please post a [minimal, complete and verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: In most languages, a list is displayed one element at a time inside `[]` or `{}` and separated by commas. To do this, you need to iterate over the list one node at a time.

Comment: On a sidenote: I would strongly advise you to write your code in English, especially if you need to get help from StackOverflow or anybody else who is not fluent in French. It will help us understand you code more easily and thus also finding any problems faster.

Comment: You should post your code here as text rather than a link to a screenshot.

Comment: Please don't try to translate the code in the fly. Take your time, make sure the program as posted compiles and produces the error your original program does.

Comment: sorry I forgot some translation now should be ok

Answer (score 0):

Since linked list is a data structure that has the elements linked one after the other,in order to print the whole list you have to traverse the whole list and print the elements one by one until you reach the NULL pointer.

it should be like

```
while(head!=NULL)
{
    printf("%d",head->data);
    head=head->next;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try using a temporary `ELEMENT` variable and assigning `p_head` to `temp`

```
        void liste_display(ELEMENT **p_head)
        { 
            temp = (ELEMENT*) malloc (sizeof(ELEMENT));
            temp = *p_head;
            while(temp != NULL) 
            { 
                 printf("%d",temp->nb_products); 
                 temp= temp->next;
             }
         }
```

Answer (score -1):

Edit:

```
while(p_tete != NULL){
     printf("%d",p_tete->produit_nb);
     p_tete = p_tete->suivant;
}
```

Comment: This wouldn't display the last element.

Comment: Yup, it has to be `while (p_tete)` or `while (p_tete != NULL)`.